# How can I make sending links from browser to mail client work on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, email

When I click on "Send link" in Firefox, a window that looks like Internet Explorer pops up and tells me that my default mail client isn't properly installed. The mail client, which is set as default) is Thunderbird.

I tried searching the rest of the internets without any success.

- Yes, I have tried to set the default mail client with the utility included in Vista, but had no success.
- No, this does not seem to be related to either Firefox or Thunderbird. At least that bit I learned from my googling. Others are having the same problem with IE and Windows Mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I could find was:

[Setting Firefox's mail client](http://support.mozilla.com/nl/kb/Changing+the+e-mail+program+used+by+Firefox)

- At the top of the Firefox window On
  the menu bar, click on the Tools
  Firefox Edit menu, and select
  Options... Preferences....
- Select the Applications panel.
- Search for the Content-type: mailto
  and select it.
- Click on the Actions column in the
  mailto row, to change the action.

  [image]
- Always ask will prompt you each time you use a mail function for which
  program or service to use.
- Use  (default) will automatically launch your operating
  system's e-mail program (e.g. Thunderbird, Outlook, Entourage, Evolution) to its message composition window.
- For instructions on how to change your operating system's default e-mail program, see the next section of this article.
- Use  will open your webmail service's (e.g. Yahoo! Mail, Gmail, Hotmail) message composition page inside Firefox. For more information
  about using webmail services, see the
  Using webmail services section of
  this article.
- Use other... will let
  you specify an external program for
  Firefox to launch.
- Application
  Details... will let you view
  information about or remove the
  webmail services that Firefox can
  use.

Click OK to close the Options
window

Click Close to close the
Preferences windowClose the
Preferences window

Or read this:

> The default mail client is the program that opens when you click a link in another application to send a mail message, for example, when you click on a mailto link or when you click File -> Send link" in Firefox. Note that the default mail client is not as much of an issue when using Mozilla Suite/SeaMonkey because the browser and mail components are integrated (e.g., a mailto link in a SeaMonkey browser window should open SeaMonkey Mail, regardless of your default mail client).
>
> This article describes how to
> configure Thunderbird as the default
> e-mail client. However, you must also
> configure any other e-mail clients you
> run to not attempt to be the default
> e-mail client or it will have no
> effect. For example, in Outlook
> Express you may need to press a button
> in "Tools -> Options -> General ->
> Default Messaging Programs" to make
> the dialog box say "This application
> is NOT the default mail handler". Note
> that the calendar in Outlook will not
> work unless Outlook is the default
> email client.
>
> You do not need to make Thunderbird
> the default email client in order to
> send/receive email. It's used mainly
> to allow other applications to use
> Thunderbird to send a message by
> making SimpleMAPI calls (if your
> operating system supports MAPI) , or
> by your clicking on a mailto: URL (in
> a browser). It also associates
> Thunderbird with the .EML file
> extension under Windows (if you're
> running 1.5 or later) so that if you
> double click on a .EML file its
> displayed in Thunderbird.
>
> Note: If you receive a message such as
> Firefox doesn’t know how to open this
> address because the protocol (mailto)
> isn’t associated with any program.
> that means that no mail client is
> currently set as the default and you
> will need to set one.
>
> In Thunderbird, go to "Tools ->
> Options -> General" and select "Use
> Thunderbird as the default mail
> application". (In the Mozilla Suite,
> go to "Edit -> Preferences -> Mail &
> Newsgroups" and select "Use Mozilla
> Mail as the default mail
> application".) If that doesn't take
> effect right away, try restarting
> Thunderbird or even the computer once.
>
> If that still doesn't work then
> another email client (such as Outlook
> or Windows Mail) is probably also
> configured to be the default email
> client. If you're using Windows Vista
> go to "Start -> Default Programs ->
> Set Program Access and Computer
> Defaults" and set "Mozilla
> Thunderbird" as your default e-mail
> application. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776877.aspx) at
> msdn.microsoft.com for more
> information.
>
> If you're running Windows XP another
> solution would be to download the
> [DefaultMail](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/defaultmail.htm) utility and use it to
> set the default e-mail client. It can
> also do this on a per-user basis.
> That's useful if several people share
> a machine (with their own Windows user
> account) and each wants to use a
> different e-mail client as the default
> e-mail client. If none of these
> methods work it might be because your
> windows account doesn't have the
> rights to modify the registry. Try
> using the "run as" command to
> temporarily run a command/application
> as a administrator.

Comment: Sweet! :D Good to hear it worked

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you've tried setting Thunderbird as the default mail client using Vista's utility, but have you tried doing it from within Thunderbird itself? I don't have Thunderbird here at work, but I believe the General tab of the options dialog allows you to do this.

Apologies if you've already attempted this method, but I'm pretty sure this is how I set Thunderbird as the default mail client on my Vista-based laptop.

**UPDATE**: Just found [this thread](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=tr&comments_parentId=12118&forumId=1), which seems to describe the same problem as you're having. First it suggests changing your default mail client to be Windows Mail, then putting it back to Thunderbird to re-attempt the required registry changes for the association. If that doesn't there is further discussion of editing the registry directly. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I tried this. Thunderbird is even set to check whether it's the default client each time it starts. But it was worth a try. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am sorry to report that the trick of changing default mail clients didn't work for me. I will have to unearth the registry information now. But to be honest, when I first googled the problem and found forums like that, I thought: Thank god for superuser.com. Hmm. Now it's back to those forums.

Comment: Sorry to hear you're still having trouble. I hope the registry tweaks in that thread help!

Comment: Any update on your progress?

Comment: Yep. Thanks for asking and sorry to tell you that Ivo hit the jackpot.

Comment: No need to be sorry, glad you got it fixed! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps in [this link](http://lifehacker.com/392287/set-firefox-3-to-launch-gmail-for-mailto-links), but choose Thunderbird as the program instead of GMail.

If that doesn't work, can you click on regular **mailto:** links? I believe the issue is with the handling of **mailto:** - Windows doesn't know that there's a program able to handle it.

Comment: I will try this if you tell me the Thunderbird URL.

Comment: It might well be that Windows doesn't know how to handle mailto links. What I'm looking for is a way to teach it how to handle them.